# Getting a list of connections opened with JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to know if there exists an annotation or object that gets the open connections in JBoss so they can be closed, and so avoid leaks in the situation where I kill a thread that still has connections opened. I'm using JBoss 4.2.3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I *hope* I've made sense of this question correctly; all other interpretations that I could think of were more bizarre.

Comment: Well thanks, for edit my question i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely there will be an annotation or object that will hold all open connections, as this could be very tricky from a security standpoint.

I understand managing leaky applications can be a bit of an emergency, so if you just need a quick win, an AspectJ pointcut that finds all open connections that haven't been closed within a certain period of time might be useful. I haven't actually tried it, but this might be useful:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aopwork10/

Alternatively, a decent profiler can go a long way (JProfiler is what I use and recommend at the moment).